# Can object.Equals(Nothing) ever be true?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm going through some old code base in VB.NET (ASP.NET with VB.NET in code-behind), with .NET Framework 3.5, and often I see this:

```
Dim ddlSomeDropDown As DropDownList
ddlSomeDropDown = CType(fvSomeFormView.FindControl("ddlSomeDropDown"), DropDownList)

If Not ddlSomeDropDown.Equals(Nothing) Then
    '...
```

As I understand it, it's a safeguard, but if `ddlSomeDropDown` ever happened to be `Nothing`, there would be a null reference exception on calling its `.Equals` function, no? So, can `ddlSomeDropDown.Equals(Nothing)` ever be true *in this context*? Alternately, can `anyObject.Equals(Nothing)` ever be true?

Comment: [`Nothing` is not null.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> often I see this:

Where do you see this. It will throw a `NullrefernceException` if the control is `Nothing`.

> .. As I understand it, it's a safeguard, but if ddlSomeDropDown ever
>   happened to be Nothing, there would be a null reference exception

Exactly. It is not a safeguard.

> So, can `anyObject.Equals(Nothing)` ever be true?

Of course it can if you want:

```
Public Class TypeWithStrangeEquals
    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return True
        Else
            ' ...'
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Does that make sense? No. It is bad practice.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-6):

> Implementations of Equals must not throw exceptions; they should
>   always return a value. For example, **if obj is Nothing, the Equals
>   method should return false** instead of throwing an
>   ArgumentNullException.

You could use the `Shared` method `Object.Equals(obj1, obj2)`, but that will return `False` if one or both objects are `Nothing`.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

> It determines whether either objA or objB is null. If so, it returns
>   false.

**Edit**: as pmcoltrane mentioned correctly in a comment `Nothing` in VB.NET has the same effect as `default` in C#, it will return the default value for a given type. With reference types it means (same as C#) `null`, but with value types like `Date` or `Int32` it will return the default value(`01/01/0001 00:00:00` for date and `0` for numeric values).

Thats why this returns `True`:

```
Dim isZeroNothing = 0.Equals(Nothing) ' true
```

By the way, in C# this is `false` because `null` has not the `default`-effect:

```
bool isZeroNothing = 0.Equals(null);  // false
```

Comment: I understand that the OP talks about the instance that call Equals being Nothing and of course that will raise the exception NULL.Equals(something)

Comment: @Steve: i hope i've clarified now that it doesn't help to prevent a NullRefernceException. It doesn't make any sense at all and i've never seen it either.

Comment: This can happen with value types, since `Nothing` seems to mean `default`. You can write `Dim i as Integer = Nothing : Dim j as Integer? = Nothing : Console.WriteLine(i.Equals(Nothing)) : Console.WriteLine(j.Equals(Nothing))` and see `True` twice on the console. Doesn't really apply to a DropDownList, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call any method on a null (Nothing) instance you will get the `NullReferenceException`. That's a given.

Those lines are dangerous because if it ever happens to get back a Nothing then your code traps.
I would replace those lines with

```
If ddlSomeDropDown IsNot Nothing Then
```